# How can I transfer a python object for use in a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, python, bottle

I'm using Bottle and Python 2.7.

I would like to pass a list variable from my Bottle's controller to the view page, where it will be used in a JavaScript variable.

```
@app.route('/foo'):
def foo():
    l = [{'name':'Matthew'}]
    return template('foo', l=l)
```

I've also done:

```
l = json.dumps([{'name':'Matthew'}]
```

In my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready({
        var l = {{l}}
        l.forEach(function(entry) {
            console.log(entry);
        });
    });
</script>
```

However my console says I have a syntax error. When I open the HTML, it is rendered like:

```
var l = [{&quot;name&quot;: &quot;Matthew&quot;]
```

How can I transfer a python object for use in a JavaScript variable?

Answer (score 1):

The substitutions between `{{` and `}}` are [HTML Entity encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) to prevent XSS amongst other things.

Try this:

```
var l = {{!l}};
```

Comment: Is it unsafe if I do this?

Comment: It's unsafe if `l` was user-generated content. It's not unsafe if you *know* that `l` contains only valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Bottle (via, the SimpleTemplate engine) is escaping the output to prevent XSS vulnerability. This is good, generally. You can disable the escaping temporarily using `!` like:

```
var l = {{!l}};
```

The docs for it are [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#inline-expressions)

Comment: Is it unsafe if I do this?

Comment: It's safest to assume not, hence it being escaped by default. It can be though, depending on the source of the data. If it comes from a trusted source, such as a developer or (maybe) an admin, it might be okay. Otherwise, no.